# Check if an action is currently running?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to check if there are actions currently running in a CCNode class in Cocos2d? I'd like to know if a `CCMoveBy` is still running or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a method to indicate when the method is finished, and then toggle some BOOL or something like that to indicate it is not running, and put a start method to toggle the BOOL to indicate it started:

```
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration 
 position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];

id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];

id actionMoveStarted = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
selector:@selector(spriteMoveStarted:)];

[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMoveStarted, actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```

Modified from [here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial)

In the two @selector methods:

```
-(void) spriteMoveStarted:(id)sender {
    ccMoveByIsRunning = YES;
}
```

and:

```
-(void) spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender {
    ccMoveByIsRunning = NO;
}
```

where ccmoveByIsRunning is the BOOL I'm referring to.

**EDIT**: As xus has pointed out, you should actually not do this and instead use `[self numberOfRunningActions]` as others have pointed out.

Comment: this is an ugly hack, [self numberOfRunningActions] should be used (as commented below)

Comment: @xus: Good point. My bad, I can't delete the answer because he accepted it already, but I have pointed out my mistake thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[self numberOfRunningActions]` on any CCNode. In your case, it sounds like you want to know if there are simply any actions running or not, so it's not a big deal to know the exact number beforehand.

Answer (score 5):

We can easily check if specific actions run by using **getActionByTag** method and **action.tag** property. 
There is no need to introduce the **CCCallFuncN** callbacks or counting **numberOfRunningActions**.

*Example.*

In our app it is important to let the jumpAction to be finished prior to executing another jump. To prevent triggering another jump during an already running jump action 
the critical jump section of code is protected as follows:

```
#define JUMP_ACTION_TAG   1001

-(void)jump {
    // check if the action with tag JUMP_ACTION_TAG is running:
    CCAction *action = [sprite getActionByTag:JUMP_ACTION_TAG]; 

    if(!action) // if action is not running execute the section below:
    {
        // create jumpAction:
        CCJumpBy *jumpAction = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:jumpDuration position:ccp(0,0) height:jumpHeight jumps:1];

        // assign tag JUMP_ACTION_TAG to the jumpAction:
        jumpAction.tag = JUMP_ACTION_TAG;

        [sprite runAction:jumpAction];    // run the action
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this method of checking to see if an action was running. My app of thousands of line of code had one massive glitch that was finally fixed by the method in your code. Thank you.